# How to add HTML element inside of exist div, but cover content?

Tags: jquery, html

For example I HTML like that:

```
<div class='title-post'>The content</div>
```

Now, I want use Jquery to add element to have result like this:

```
<div class='title-post'><span>The content</span></div>
```

It means I add `<span></span>` cover the content.

How can I use Jquery to do that?

Thank for your help.

Comment: downvoter comment? I am not good so I need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use JQuery API `wrapInner` : http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

*Demo* http://jsfiddle.net/rp3bY/

**Code**

```
$('.title-post').wrapInner('<span>');
```

Comment: Yes, better than mine answer. I did not know that this function exists ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One line of jQuery:

```
$('.title-post').html($('<span />').text($('.title-post').text()));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P6B8g/